# What IEEE standatd SQLLite uses for storing REAL values? Does it store IEEE 754 double lossless?

Tags: ieee-754

There are two different IEEE standards for floating-point computation. IEEE 754 (b = 2) and IEEE 854(b = 2 or b = 10). [SQLLite wiki](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses)  says:

> REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

I need to store IEEE 754 double in SQLLite column and later read this value (no need any arithmetic). Can I be confident that I will read the **same** binary value (754 has unique binary representation), including all kinds of NaN, etc. (in other words: is SQLLite lossless with regard to IEEE754 doubles)?

Answer (score 1):

<s>I think it depends on the sqlite version</s> (It doesn't, read below)

I've found other definitions for REAL:

> REAL: The value is a floating-point number, stored as an 8-byte value
>   in the processor's native format. For most modern processors, this is
>   an IEEE 754 double-precision number. Literal floating-point numbers
>   are represented by any bare series of numeric digits that include a
>   decimal point or exponent.

[Source](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/viz_api_dev_guide/content/sqllite.htm)

A similar definition is found in O'Reily [Using Sqlite](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=v5OYlkt6uKYC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=sqlite%20double-precision%20IEEE%20floating%20point%20numbers.&source=bl&ots=hcW-qs_ONB&sig=QvnWrtUUF-9gmZFfHJkbBxrf7t4&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjxpy_gLXMAhVEhpAKHf_qAScQ6AEIKzAC#v=snippet&q=ieee&f=false)

But latest sqlite3 says IEEE, so it is IEEE 754

---

**EDIT:**

Sqlite version 2.* was [typeless](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html).

[the oldest version of the doc](http://web.archive.org/web/20040617020341/http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)  I've found matches with sqlite 3.0.0 alpha release date and has not changed.

The books I cited might have been based on pre alpha documentation.